# Date format issue in Firefox browser

Tags: angularjs, date, firefox

My code

```
for(n in data.values){
        data.values[n].snapshot = new Date(data.values[n].snapshot);
        data.values[n].value = parseInt(data.values[n].value);
        console.log(data.values[n].snapshot);
}
```

here console.log shows perfect date in Chrome as 'Thu Aug 07 2014 14:29:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)', but in Firefox it is showing as 'Invalid Date'.

If I console.log(data.values[n].snapshot) before the new Date line, it is showing date as

```
2014-08-07 14:29
```

How can I convert the date format to Firefox understandable way.

Answer (score 0):

The Date object only officially accepts two formats:

1. `Mon, 25 Dec 1995 13:30:00 GMT`
2. `2011-10-10T14:48:00`

This means that your date `2014-08-07 14:29` is invalid.

Your date can be easily made compatible with the second date format though (assuming that date is yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm):

```
for(n in data.values){
    n = n.replace(/\s/g, "T");
    data.values[n].snapshot = new Date(data.values[n].snapshot);
    data.values[n].value = parseInt(data.values[n].value);
    console.log(data.values[n].snapshot);
}
```